# Loop with numbers in rows of the csv file

Tags: python, loops, csv, while-loop, iterator

I wrote a python script to run a sql in PostgreSQL,

```
import sys, os, math
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop')
print os.getcwd()

#set up psycopg2 environment
import psycopg2

#shortest_path module
query = """
    select *
    from shortest_path ($$
        select
            gid as id,
            source::int4 as source,
            target::int4 as target,
            cost::double precision as cost,
            rcost::double precision as reverse_cost
        from network
        $$, %s, %s, %s, %s
    )
"""

#make connection between python and postgresql
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'test' user = 'postgres' host = 'localhost' password = 'xxxx'")
cur = conn.cursor()

#count rows in the table
cur.execute("select count(*) from network")
result = cur.fetchone()
k = result[0] + 1                #number of points = number of segments + 1

#run loops
#import csv module
import csv
import tempfile

element = []
i = 1
l = 1
filename = 'pi_value.csv'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    while i <= k:
        while l <= k:
            cur.execute(query, (i, l, True, True))
            element = cur.fetchall()
            product = sum([a[-1] for a in element[:-1]])
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
            writer.writerow([product])
            element = []
            l = l + 1
        l = 1
        i = i + 1
```

You can see that I used iterators from i to k(and l to k) to do the while loop, now I got a csv file containing numbers I want the **iterator i and l** to be. For example, here's the csv file,

[image]

I want the iterator to loop through using the number in every row starting from the first one, like in the innermost while loop, **l = 6, l = 31, l = 28,..., l = 17, i is starting from 6 too, but only moves to i = 31 as l moves to 17 and back to l = 6, and so on.**

How to write additional lines to read this csv file and let the iterator in the while loop to run loops as those numbers in the file？

---

**Update#1**

I tried this,

```
element = []

with open('tc_sta_id.csv') as f1, open('pi_value.csv', 'wb') as f2:
csvs = csv.reader(f1)
col_num = 0
rows = list(csvs)
k = len(rows)
for row in csvs:
    i = row[col_num]
    l = row[col_num]
    while i <= k:
        while l <= k:
            cur.execute(query, (i, l, True, True))
            element = cur.fetchall()
            product = sum([a[-1] for a in element[:-1]])
            writer = csv.writer(f2, delimiter = ',')
            writer.writerow([product])
            element = []
            l = l + 1
        l = row[col_num]
        i = i + 1
```

the script runs fine, but there are all blank in the output csv file, please give me suggestions to fix this!

Comment: are you sure you get anything from the query?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to loop with two iterators in the query.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do but maybe you should read the csv twice and iterate independently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question has changed quite a bit since the start, I'm just adding this as a seperate answer. So this is an answer specifically to your update 1.

The condition for your while loop is wrong. Your condition is based on the number of rows in your csv (8 in your example). You compare this with the numbers found in the csv (so 6, 31, ...). This means your while loops stop every time you hit the second number (31 > 8). Moreover you're not jumping to the next element of your csv, but you just add 1. I haven't tried to run your code, but I think your looping over: i=6,7,8 with l=6,7,8 for each value of i. Then it tries with 31, stops immediately as it does with the rest (they're all over 8).

I'm not entirely sure what you want as you seem to keep wanting to use extra while loops for something, and I'm not sure what you want to use them for (can't find it in your question, everything in your question implies for loops only).

I'm also not sure whether i and l come from the same csv or not. I made you a solution where you can easily make i and l come from different csvs, but I set them at the beginning to come from the same one. If they come from the same csv, you cannot just nest the for loops with the same iterator, so we cheat and extract them into a list (I tested this with a simple example).

```
rows = list(csvs) #convert to a list to avoid problems with iterating over the same iterator
csv_for_i = rows
csv_for_l = rows
for row_i in csv_for_i:
    i = row_i[col_num]
    for row_l in csv_for_l:
        l = row_l[col_num]
        cur.execute(query, (i, l, True, True))
        element = cur.fetchall()
        product = sum([a[-1] for a in element[:-1]])
        writer = csv.writer(f2, delimiter = ',')
        writer.writerow([product])
        element = []
```

Let me know if this works. If so, accept the answer and I'll think about how to make the question and the answers into something that works more nicely on stack overflow. Currently, there are actually multiple questions and answers here and that's confusing for other people searching for answers.

---

Just for info, a small example on pitfalls with iterators (made with csv, but it goes for all iterators).

```
import csv

# test.csv contents:
#
#6
#31
#17

print 'Case 1:'
with open('test.csv') as f1:
    csv1 = csv.reader(f1)
    csv2 = csv.reader(f1)
    for el1 in csv1:
        for el2 in csv2:
            print el1, el2
# Results
#
#['6'] ['31']
#['6'] ['17']

print 'Case 2:'
with open('test.csv') as f1:
    csvs = csv.reader(f1)
    rows = list(csvs)
    for el1 in rows:
        for el2 in rows:
            print el1, el2
# Results
#
#['6'] ['6']
#['6'] ['31']
#['6'] ['17']
#['31'] ['6']
#['31'] ['31']
#['31'] ['17']
#['17'] ['6']
#['17'] ['31']
#['17'] ['17']

print 'Case 3:'
with open('test.csv') as f1, open('test.csv') as f2:
    for el1 in csv.reader(f1):
        for el2 in csv.reader(f2):
            print el1, el2
# Results
#
#['6'] ['6']
#['6'] ['31']
#['6'] ['17']

print 'Case 4:'
with open('test.csv') as f1, open('test.csv') as f2:
    csv1 = csv.reader(f1)
    csv2 = csv.reader(f2)
    for el1 in csv1:
        for el2 in csv2:
            print el1, el2
# Results
#
#['6'] ['6']
#['6'] ['31']
#['6'] ['17']
```

Answer (score 1):

col_num is the column number in which you have your i values

```
with open('yourfile') as file:
    csv = csv.reader(file)
    next(csv) # skip the header
    col_num = 0
    for row in csv:
        i = row[col_num]
        while i <= k:
            cur.execute(query, (i, 100000000000, True, True))
            rs.append(cur.fetchall())
            i = i + 1
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I typed a wrong description in my post in the very beginning, and now I have edited it, please give me suggestions if you got time, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I made you a short test using just simple python functionality.

```
f = open('test.csv')
csvlines = f.readlines()
f.close()
numbers = [int(n.split(',')[0]) for n in csvlines]
```

You might have to replace ',' with ';' or something else depending on the locale settings of your operating system.

Short explanation:
csvlines will contain the rows of your csv as strings, f.e. ['1,a,some text', '2,b,some other text']. You will go through each of those lines and call split on the line, e.g. '1,a,some text'.split(',') will give ['1','a','some text']. Your first column will then need to be cast to an integer because it currently is still a string.

Use in your code as (edited as question was edited):

```
for i in numbers:
    if(i<k):
        for l in numbers:
            # not sure what your constraint on k is, but you can stop iterating 
            # through the numbers with a simple if
            if(l<k):
                #do work (you can use i an l here, they will automatically 
                # take the next value each iteration of the for loop 
                #(try print i, l for example): 6,6; 6,31; ...; 6,17; 31,6; 31,31
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I made a mistake in my post, and I have corrected it. Can you please give me the answer to the corrected post？ thank you very much.

Comment: I tried, but doesn't work, and I have edited my post, if you got ideas, please tell me, thanks a lot!